# Ceiling Fan Replacement - Wiring Issue

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a ceiling fan in one room and when I took the old one down I found 2 black wires tied together(one of which is hot), one white ground wire, one hot white wire, and one red wire, and a copper ground coming from the ceiling. I only have one switch in the room to operate the light. The fan was wired hot and turned on and off by the pull chain.

I know the red switch wire attaches to the blue wire in the new fan.
I know the two white ground wires connect
I know the green wire in the fan connects to the ground.

I cannot figure out what to do with the remaining three wires. As a side note - disconnecting the fan in here has also caused power going to the other sections of the room on this breaker loose power.

Comment: Please double check the number of wires you have. You're missing at least one bare copper wire. A picture of the box showing where the wires come out would be helpful.

Comment: I will try to get a picture. The ceiling has two black wires, two white wires, a  red wire, and a copper ground wire in the fan box. The new fan has a blue wire, a green wire, a white wire, and a black wire.

Comment: How was the old fixture wired?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure - my husband took it down and doesn't remember now.

Answer (score -3):

Odd that you said you had a white wire that was hot. Both white wires should be neutral and have no voltage. Seems to me wires would go like this: connect all black wires together. That will run hot all the time to the fan as well as sending power downstream.   Next tie all white wires together. That will provide neutral to the fan as well as pass neutral downstream. Ideally there would be a bare copper wire coming from the hot side and another to continue downstream. The red to blue should switch the light, providing that blue is the correct one for the light.

Comment: Making assumptions about wiring can be quite dangerous, especially when you have such little information to base it on.

Comment: If she actually has a white wire that is hot (and he says he does), she CANNOT connect it to other white wires or she will trip the circuit breaker (or fuse). As @Tester101 says ...